# jQuery('#divElement').html(str) does not work inside onsuccess - $.ajax({ type: "POST",....,onsuccess , )

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm dealing with an issue that make me crazy. I want to build the pages dynamically, but when the POST success (return from my web service, using  $.ajax({ type: "POST",....,onsuccess , ) the onsuccess function called which should build a page.

If I call the onsuccess from the onready directly, it works fine the page appear. but when the onsuccess function called due to return from the web service I can't see the page (The onsuccess func called for sure, I also see that the page element their - using Chrome "Inspect element" ), any one can explain me Why I can't see the page!!!!?!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>My Page</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function DebugClient(data, fnSuccess, fnError) {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "Service/WcaService.asmx/Client_GetInfo",
               data: '{"id": ' + data + '}',
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           success: fnSuccess,
           error: fnError,
           dataFilter: function (data) {
               //remove the ‘d’ property inserted by all WCF services (if it exists)
               return data.replace(/^\{"d":(.*)\}$/, "$1");
           }
       });
   }
 $(document).ready(function () {

    //If I call the onSuccess directly from here it works.


   DebugClient(currentID, onSuccess, DefaultErrorHandler);
   return false;
 }

function onSuccess(res) {              
   var html = '';

     html += '<div data-role="page">';

     html += '<div data-role="header">';
     html += '<h1>My Title</h1>';
     html += '</div>';

     html += '<div data-role="content">';
     html += '<p>Hello world</p> ';
     html += '</div>';

     html += '</div>';
     jQuery('#divData').html(html);
     return false;
 });
</script>

<div id="divData"> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So... is `onSuccess` being called?

Comment: Again if I call onsuccess from onready: 
$(document).ready(function () 
{ onSuccess(); 
return false; } it is work. In addition the onsuccess been called from ajax with complete res value (the return value is a list of stuff, and it been passed from my web service successfully), but I'm ignoring the return value just untill I be able to see the dynamic UI.

Comment: Yes- onSuccess being called with correct return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, it is simply using the $(page).appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer) instead of JQuery(XXX).html, I remark the changes in Red for simplicity and few comments in Green , hope this will be useful and helpful, I can't find complete solution for this scenario, so I add it for any one need it.

Thanks guys.

TAG: how to create page in run time according to return value from WEB Service / WCF

Here the complete solution:
http://bit.ly/vjuPSw

Answer (score 4):

Your ajax call specifies `fnSuccess`.  Your function is `onSuccess`.

Further, it looks like the ajax call might be in the global scope, but the `onSuccess()` function is inside a `$(document).ready()` callback which  means it isn't available in the global scope.

Comment: More specifically he has syntax error in his code. It would be easier to see if the code was sanely formatted.

Comment: fnSuccess is the parameter on the DebugClient!
and both are in global space, I mansion that the onsuccess been called successfully via the ajax in success, and the elements appeared inside the <div id="divData"> , but I can't see them, I also tried $("#divData").show();

Comment: liho1eye: where you see syntax error?
the "currentID" is missing here but it defined var currentID = 1;
Again if I call onsuccess from onready:

$(document).ready(function () {
   onSuccess()
   return false;
 }

it is work.
In addition the onsuccess been called from ajax with complete res value (the return value is a list of stuff, and it been passed from my web service successfully), but I'm ignoring the return value just untill I be able to see the dynamic UI.

Comment: @Joseph look at where your onSuccess function defined. That can't possibly be right and is causing confusion to people. Try to indent your code properly and You'll see it right away.